# how to do http request using libreoffice basic macros

Tags: httprequest, libreoffice-basic

I want to write a macro on a LibreOffice spreadsheet, to send an HTTP request to an web URL and receive a JSON like response. Can i do it with LibreOffice basic macro programming? Where can i get information about the API.

I really appreciate any tips.

Thanks

Comment: Does [WEBSERVICE and FILTERXML](https://help.libreoffice.org/index.php?title=Calc/WEBSERVICE&Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=5.3#bm_id3150028) do what you need?

Comment: I don't know. When i put that on the basic macro, it says that the routine WEBSERVICE is not defined

Comment: They are Calc formulas, not Basic functions.  Enter them in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ho i see. But the intention is to write a macro in basic to do some tasks via webservices.

Answer (score 7):

I'm too late to help Antonio, but for posterity...

You can call spreadsheet functions from Basic, as explained in the [open office docs](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Function_Handling). Here's a simple example that invokes the `WEBSERVICE()` function:

```
Function GetWebContent(url As string) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim funtionAccess As Object
    functionAccess = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")

    GetWebContent = functionAccess.callFunction("WEBSERVICE",Array(url))

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    GetWebContent = "Error " & Err
End Function


Function Test

    Dim url As String
    url = "http://www.google.com"

    Dim response As String
    response = GetWebContent(url)

End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException when I use an "https" address instead of an "http" address - is that just not allowed??